# WindowManagerBadTokenException unable to add window

Tags: java, android

I have an error below:

```
  //TODO tryAgain
private void tryAgain(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Game Over")
    .setMessage("Times Up!")
    .setPositiveButton("Try Again?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent retry = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(retry);
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("Back to Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_3.this, ShapingColors.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
     })
     .show();   
}
```

Basically what I want to do is cancel the dialog then restart my current activity and the other one I want to go back to menu activity. What am I missing in here? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE LOGCAT:**

```
   04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40515dc0 is not valid; is your activity running?
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.say.shapingcolor.Stage1_3.tryAgain(Stage1_3.java:307)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.say.shapingcolor.Stage1_3.access$0(Stage1_3.java:287)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.say.shapingcolor.Stage1_3$MyCount.onFinish(Stage1_3.java:319)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 04-27 00:42:44.680: E/AndroidRuntime(330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is at line no. 307 and 287 of Stage1_3.java(is this your activity?)

Comment: .show(); = 307 and private void tryAgain(){ = 287

Comment: @neknekmouh First of all what happened when you use the above? When will this problem occured? is dialog opened or you get this error onclick of Cancel button. Let me know

Comment: This problem occurs every time I go to the next activity. @Pragnani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur when you are showing the dialog for a context that no longer exists. When you are calling `show()` of dialog the activity is destroyed. This happens generally after async operations. Make sure that your activity(in which you want to show dialog) is running.

Don't call the activity after finishing it just create a new intent and start the activity. Do like this:

```
private void tryAgain(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Game Over")
    .setMessage("Times Up!")
    .setPositiveButton("Try Again?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent retry = new Intent(this, Stage1_3.class);//I guess Stage1_3 is the current activity
            finish();
            startActivity(retry);
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("Back to Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent i = new Intent(Stage1_3.this, ShapingColors.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
     })
     .show();   
}
```

Comment: When I go to other activity, the previous activity is destroyed because I put finish() method in it. How do I deal with this?

Comment: So I changed like this: Intent retry = new Intent(Stage1_3.this, Stage1_3.class);